# Convert '%m/%d/%Y' string index into pandas datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

MY index is datetime string with format `'%m/%d/%Y' ('09/26/2007')`

When I try to convert the index into datetime index using `pd.to_datetime` function `pd.to_datetime(df.index)`, I got error message `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00`

It looks like pandas can't detect the right string format, how I can convert the index into datetime index?

Thanks

Comment: The `pd.to_datetime()` can detect this format. Actually I have one row missing index, which causes the error. Check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The the look of the error message, it appears you may have the string `'1/1/0001'` in your index. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2], index=['09/26/2007', '1/1/0001'])
pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

raises

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

This error arises because the DatetimeIndex uses an array of NumPy `datetime64[ns]`s which can not represent the date 0001-01-01. The `datetime64[ns]` dtype can only represent [dates in the range `[1678 AD, 2262 AD]`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units).

There is a [pandas github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7307) discussing this limitation.

For now, the recommended solution is to use a PeriodIndex instead of a DatetimeIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2], index=['09/26/2007', '1/1/0001'])
df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq='D')
```

yields

```
            0
2007-09-26  1
1-01-01     2
```

Comment: I tried `df[df.index == '1/1/0001']`, it is empty. I am not sure how I can find that bad date, cause it shouldn't exist.

Comment: Try `df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')`. (This will turn invalid strings into `NaT` (not-a-time) objects.) Then look at `df.loc[pd.isnull(df['dates'])]`.

Comment: Thanks! I found that date, it misses the date. The index on that row is empty. After dealing with it, `pd.to_datetime()` works perfect. Thanks a lot!